# Clear Canvas with menu item onclick android

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, paint

I'm making an android paint application for education, I'm almost done but the last thing I need is to clear screen(canvas). I have no idea how to do this, also did some research but with the knowledge I have, i couldn't understand some of it.

```
public class SingleTouchEventView extends View {
  private Paint paint = new Paint();
  private Path path = new Path();

  public SingleTouchEventView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(5f);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);

  }

  @Override
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float eventX = event.getX();
    float eventY = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
      path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
      return true;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
      path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
      break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
      // nothing to do
      break;
    default:
      return false;
    }

    // Schedules a repaint.
    invalidate();
    return true;
  }

  // KLEUR  switch statement
  void setColor(int i){

      switch (i){
         case 1:

             paint.setColor(Color.RED);

         break;

         case 2:

             paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);

         break;

         case 3:

             paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);

         break;

         default:

             paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);

         break;  

      }

    }
  // LIJN DIKTE  switch statement
  void setStrokeWidth(int k){

      switch (k){
         case 5:

             paint.setStrokeWidth(12f);

         break;

         case 4:

             paint.setStrokeWidth(5f);

         break;

        default:

             paint.setStrokeWidth(5f);

         break;  

      }

    }
}
```

The code above is the SingleTouchEventView.java

and the code below is the main SingleTouchActivity.java

```
public class SingleTouchActivity extends Activity {

    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
         SingleTouchEventView stev = new SingleTouchEventView(this, null);
            setContentView(stev);
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                    return true;
            }
            if (id == R.id.ResetAction) {

                    return true;
            }if (id == R.id.LijnDun) {
                stev.setStrokeWidth(4);
                    return true;
            }if (id == R.id.LijnDik) {
                stev.setStrokeWidth(5);
                    return true;
            }
            if (id == R.id.LijnGroen) {
                stev.setColor(3);//GROEN
                    return true;
            }
            if (id == R.id.LijnBlauw) {
                    stev.setColor(2);//for blue color
                    return true;
            }
            if (id == R.id.LijnRood) {
                       stev.setColor(1);//for red color

                       return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

In SingleTouchActivity.Java i have a menuitem with the id ResetAction
whenever I click that in the menu item I want to clear the canvas. 
I hope someone is able to help me, and  I also apologize for my bad English, its not my native language

Answer (score 0):

[path.reset()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html#reset%28%29) should clear up your canvas once you perform your next redraw.

So just add this method to your SingleTouchEventView class

```
public void reset() {
    path.reset();
}
```

**However**, you create a new instance of SingleTouchEventView which creates different instances of paint. I suggest you use a single instance of SingleTouchEventView to manage the whole canvas instead of multiple instances. If not, then calling reset() would only clear anything drawn from the last time you created an instance. Although, if this is the behavior you want, then you would need to at least keep track of every instance you've created in a list so that you can change them when needed.

Comment: Thank your for the answer, where in SingleTouchEventView do I add that code?

Comment: Add the method anywhere in the class. You could add it after setStrokeWidth if you wish, it's up to you.